# Cannot delete attachment from a list item from a sharepoint online app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, attachments

I get a success message after running the following code displayed below.  However, when I go and verify the list item the file is still there. If I try the client side of this code, the file gets deleted, I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

```
function initialize(){
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";     
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest); 

  function execCrossDomainRequest() {  
            var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);                           
            var digest = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();    

            executor.executeAsync({              
                url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/getItemById(1)/AttachmentFiles/getbyFileName('test - File.xlsx')?@target='" +  hostweburl + "'",    
                type: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-Http-Method": "DELETE",
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },             
                success: function (data) {  
                    alert("success: " + JSON.stringify(data));  
                },  
                error: function (err) {  
                    alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err));  
                }    
            });                              
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to specify `type: "DELETE"` in your ajax call and also specify the matching of etag (known as entity tag).

This code demonstrates that-

```
function deleteItem (item) {     
$.ajax({
    url: item.__metadata.uri,
    type: "DELETE",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",        
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
        "If-Match": item.__metadata.etag
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("delete Successful");            
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
});
}
```

Also make sure your app has correct permission in `appmanifest` file.